# Are Facebook Messenger pop-up webviews supported on desktop browsers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am able to use Messenger webviews on the IOS Messenger app (configured as [described in the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/url-button)), but in the desktop browser the webViews always open in a new page.

Am I doing something wrong, or does Messenger in desktop web browsers simply not support the webview display modes like "compact" or "tall"?

Comment: I believe in desktop browsers, Messenger will just open url in another browser tab/window.

Comment: That's my observation as well. Was wondering if there is something special I need to do to get a more mobile experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, it is now doable.
To make a pop-up webview instead of opening a new tab, you will need to:

1) Set up proper X-Frame-Options HTTP response header to allow your pages within an iframe.

2) If the webview is to be opened from the persistent menu, you will need to set the value of the property "messenger_extensions" of the "menu_item" object to true.

Links:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/persistent-menu

Comment: Ooh, this is awesome.

Comment: @anakornk is it possible to set up the x-frame-options to enable Facebook Desktop Webviews without installing/using the SDK?

Comment: You do not have to use the JS 'SDK' script