# Messenger webview working in mobile not on desktop

Tags: facebook, chatbot, facebook-messenger

I am making messenger webview example but it is only working in mobile while form desktop it is redirecting me to a new tab,

Here is the Button payload,

```
    var buttons = [{
        type: "web_url",
        url: constant.SERVER_URL + "/checkout",
        title: "Yes",
        webview_height_ratio: "tall",
        messenger_extensions: false
    }]
```

Here is request method,

```
app.get("/checkout", function (req, res) {
    let referer = req.get('Referer');
    console.log(referer)
    if (referer) {
        if (referer.indexOf('messenger') >= 0) {
            res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.messenger.com/');
        } else if (referer.indexOf('facebook') >= 0) {
            res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com/');
        }
        res.render('checkout')
    }
});
```

Comment: Similar question was already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397701/are-facebook-messenger-pop-up-webviews-supported-on-desktop-browsers.

Comment: @kuceramI already assigned the x-frame-options, so issue is something else

Comment: I see, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttons = [{
    type: "web_url",
    url: constant.SERVER_URL + "/checkout",
    title: "Yes",
    webview_height_ratio: "tall",
    messenger_extensions: True
}]
```

The Problem was about `messenger_extensions` i made it `true` and it worked.